# React Native build failed after implementing @azesmway/react-native-unity

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, unity-game-engine

[image]

My app runs fine on Android emulator and wireless/USB debug on physical device. The issue occurs when I try to compile it as an .apk/.aab file.

I've followed the docs for integrating Unity library for Android in React Native.